# Recursão em python 3

Tags: python-3.x

```
def dobra(lista, l_dobro = []):
    if lista == []:
        return 
    else:
        dobro = lista[0] * 2
        l_dobro.append(dobro)
        dobra(lista[1:], l_dobro)
        lista = l_dobro
        return lista
```

Estou tentando fazer esta função utilizando recursão, e se eu chamo ela mais de uma vez, ele replica a lista que foi passada como parâmetro na vez anterior, a l_dobro no caso. Como posso fazer para limpar ela para a próxima instância?

Comment: tenta usar `l_dobro.clear()`

Comment: Olá Bruno, bem vindo! Fica mais facil lhe ajudar se nos dizer onde/como deseja utilizar esta função "dobra", talvez exista outras formas mais faceis de chegar no mesmo resultado. ;-)